# Loop through Python dictionary and add different values with same keys to a new dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am really stuck with this exercise. How can I with a for loop add the same keys with a new values to a different dictionary in Python?

Goal is to loops through student grades and replace them with "Excellent", "Bad", etc.

This is as far as I could get:

```py
student_scores = {
  "Harry": 81,
  "Ron": 78,
  "Hermione": 99, 
  "Draco": 74,
  "Neville": 62,
}


student_grades = {}


for key, value in student_scores.items():
    print(key, value)


print(student_grades)
```

Much appreciated in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a home work task. You do not try to change any values. Where are you stuck? You are able to iterate a dictionary - do you know how to change the value of a key? what are the rules regarding numbers to "Excellent" etc conversion - where do you code them? It is maximal unclear what you really need to do and where your problem is beside "give me the code and invent the rules yourselfs"

Comment: Thanks for the tips Patrick. I will keep this in mind next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add values to a dictionary by simply assigning the value to the dictionary indexed by the key. For example, `student_grades["Harry"] = "Excellent"`

You can do the same in your loop:

```
for key, value in student_scores.items():
    student_grades[key] = "Excellent"
```

if course, you'll not assign the same value (grade) for all keys. Use an if statement or any other conditional logic to select which grade to assign to each student. For example:

```
for key, value in student_scores.items():
    if (value > 90)
        student_grades[key] = "Excellent"
    else
        student_grades[key] = "Okey-ish"
```

Comment: Thanks Aziz, I did the loop as you advised and migrated all the grades to a new dictionary with new values successfully. Thanks a lot!